# In ObjectBox, using QueryBuilder, can I compare two Properties to each other?

Tags: objectbox

I know I can do

```
myBox.query().less(BasicAchievement_.currentSteps, 5);
```

But I want to be able to do

```
myBox.query().less(BasicAchievement_.currentSteps, BasicAchievement_.totalSteps)
```

Is this possible? I assume it would be. If not, can I join two 'tables' together (I can only really think in SQL terms, sorry)

I guess I'm asking for the equivalent of

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE currentSteps < totalSteps;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java based [query filters](http://objectbox.io/documentation/queries/#Query_filters_and_ToMany_relation) for that. Example:

```
query.filter((object) -> {
     return object.currentSteps < object.totalSteps;
})
```

We also opened a [feature request](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/349) to have that at the DB query engine.

Comment: cool, i'll look into that later and report back. Thanks again for responding so promptly