# In ObjectBox for Flutter, is there a way to compare two properties?

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I'm new to using ObjectBox, so I've been trying to do some experimenting with its query system to familarize myself with it. One of the queries I've been unable to do is a query comparing two properties. Ignoring the errors they throw, these are some examples of what I'm looking to do:

```
// Get objects where first number is bigger than second number
boxA.query(ObjectA_.firstNumber.greaterThan(ObjectA_.secondNumber))

// Get parent objects where one of its children has a specific value from the parent
parentBox.query().linkMany(ParentObject_.children, ChildObject_.name.equals(ParentObject_.favoriteChild));
```

I know [based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48403512/in-objectbox-using-querybuilder-can-i-compare-two-properties-to-each-other) that it's possible in Java using filters, but I also know that [query filters are not in ObjectBox for Dart](https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#query-filters). One of the workaround I've been testing is querying for one property, getting the values, and using each value to query for the second property. But that becomes unsustainable at even moderately sized amounts of data.

If anyone knows of a "proper" way to do this without the use of Java filters, that would be appreciated. Otherwise, if there's a more performant workaround than the one I came up with, that would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no query filter API for Dart in ObjectBox, because Dart already has the [where API](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.2/dart-core/Iterable/where.html).

E.g. for a result list write `results.where((a) => a.firstNumber >= a.secondNumber)`.